# No ORDER BY de um SELECT trocar virgula por ponto

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela em MYSQL (pode ser vista aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187ce/1 ), onde o preço esta com vírgulas e não pontos:

2,00 
2,33
11,00

Quando vou dar um order by:

```
ORDER BY preco ASC
```

O sistema entende que é uma string e coloca o 11,00 na frente, como fazer essa conversão para número no momento do ORDER BY?

Só para contar, não posso modificar a tabela, ela não é minha e não tenho essa permissão.

Comment: esse valor poderia ser um decimal?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, preciso transformar para decimal 1,00 para 1.00, 2,33 para 2.33 (basicamente substituir a virgukla por ponto ja faria ele interpretar como numero, não?

Comment: Olá, coloque aqui o create da sua tabela.

Comment: Se o valor é numérico, a solução é consertar o DB. Muito rara uma situação em que o dado deva ser armazenado no formato de exibição (no seu caso, obviamente não é adequado). Geralmente é uma falha básica de arquitetura armazenar datas e números como string, o que gera toda uma série de desvantagens.

Comment: Apareceram duas respostas que funcionam, mas vale deixar um alerta: o ideal é ter uma coluna do tipo certo, de preferência com índice, e ordenar por ela. Conversões e replaces on the fly vão certamente afetar a performance da query (o que pode ou não ser um problema no seu caso).

Comment: mas cara, se vai usar esse campo para cálculos e valores acho que é melhor você mudar para o tipo do campo. Evita esses problemas de conversões  e transtornos

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost seria o mundo ideal, mas não tenho essa permissão, só se pegar todo a tabela do cliente e copiar pra uma nova tabela, mas e se ele inserir novos produtos? Teria que ficar atualizando isso com um cronjob... mas não fui contratado pra isso...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu caso em especifico deveria ser feito a transição para o tipo `decimal(18,2)`, mas, existe uma opção que pode causar um pouco de lentidão na consulta, mas, funciona de uma maneira geral:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA
  ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(preco, '.', ''),',','.') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

[***Exemplo funcional***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187ce/2)

Comment: Legal, valeu! O que seria esse 18,2?

Comment: 18 números sendo que 16 antes da virgula com duas casas decimais, é uma formatação basica, que pode ser configurado a sua maneira. @caiocafardo

Answer (score 6):

Se o preço está com vírgulas, provavelmente o campo não é do tipo numérico.
O ideal seria você alterar o tipo do dado do campo preço.

Mas se você precisa disso rápido, tente

```
select cast(REPLACE(preco, ',', '.') as float ) p from tabela order by p
```

ou tenta dar update

```
update tabela set preco = REPLACE(preco, ',', '.');
```

depois altera o tipo do dado da coluna preco para float.

Comment: Ok para o valor especificado na pergunta, mas se ele tiver um valor 1,00.39

Comment: Nesse caso já é outro formato numérico, então fica :update tabela set preco = REPLACE(REPLACE(preco, ' ', ''),'.',',');

Answer (score 3):

Como já respondido, a única solução real é corrigir o campo da tabela.

De qualquer forma, se é para manter o "modo de compatibilidade", **se os decimais forem fixos**, isto basta, para simplificar a expressão:

```
SELECT * FROM produto ORDER BY LPAD(preco,10,'0')
```

Veja funcionando no seu próprio **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187ce/7)**.

Troque o 10 pelo máximo de casas do campo. Basicamente estamos enchendo de zeros à esquerda. O `10` é a quantidade de casas final, e o `0` o caractere de alinhamento.

Isto funciona, pois passamos a organizar as strings alfabeticamente assim:

```
 0000002,00
 0000004,10
 0000011,50
```

Comment: Oi, acha que é mais eficaz no ponto de vista de performance do que o AS DECIMAL e CAST?

Comment: @caiocafardo eu sou suspeito pra dizer, pq já tem outras respostas, mas o velho e bom teste é seu amigo :) O que posso dizer é que, se forem fixos os decimais, eu faria desta forma. O importante é você entender os riscos e vantagens de cada método e aplicar ao seu caso. Entender como funciona cada solução é o mais importante. Eu gosto da simplicidade dessa aqui, a vulnerabilidade dela é o caso de números com casas decimais em quantidades diferentes.

Comment: Fiz testes e o seu foi mais eficaz (bem mais), mas realmente não sei quantas casas decimais podem vir, até agora veio só 2, mas como o banco de dados não é meu... não posso bater o martelo!

Comment: @caiocafardo basta ver o tamanho do campo no DB. Nada impede de por casas sobrando. Tecnicamente o meu faz bem menos operações internas (nao caberia explicação no comment). Veja o tamanho do campo preço, e ponha no lugar do 10. Acho que mesmo se usasse umas 50 casas, ainda seria eficaz (internamente seria um _fill_ seguido de `strcmp`, ambas operações eficientes). Sobre a possibilidade de variar as decimais, se quem fornece o banco não puder te dar certeza, não arrisque.

Answer (score 0):

não tenho o esquema da sua tabela aqui mas tente fazer assim:

```
order by cast (preco as real)asc
```

Comment: Isso não vai dar erro de conversão justamente por causa das vírgulas?

Comment: realmente nao testei com virgula, so peguei um campo varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
order by cast(replace(valor, '.', ',') as decimal(10,2));
```